# List all virtualenv created by virtualenvwrapper

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtualenv-commands

In virtualenvwrapper, is there a simple way to list all virtualenv on my machine?

(like what yolk -l does to list all python packages in the current virtual environment?)

**CLARIFICATION:** "ls -la" in my env directory does not count. I am looking for a virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper specific command.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386421/127971

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Silly question. Found that there's a

```
lsvirtualenv
```

command which lists all existing virtualenv.

See the [command documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#lsvirtualenv).

Comment: see the command reference http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html

Comment: @Tms91 documentation is now here :) https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#lsvirtualenv

Answer (score 201):

You can use the `lsvirtualenv`, in which you have two options "long" or "brief":

"long" option is the default one, it searches for any hook you may have around this command and executes it, which takes more time.

"brief" just take the virtualenvs names and prints it.

brief usage:

```
$ lsvirtualenv -b
```

long usage:

```
$ lsvirtualenv -l
```

if you don't have any hooks, or don't even know what i'm talking about, just use "brief".

Comment: zsh: command not found: lsvirtualenv

Comment: To prevent voting people up for `command not found: lsvirtualenv`. Please do `pip install virtualenvwrapper` or use thise [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/603937/1579334) for Ubuntu

Answer (score 114):

To list all the virtual environments (if using the anaconda distribution):

```
conda info --envs
```

Hope my answer helps someone...

Comment: Great answer! `lsvirtualenv` is not recognized as an internal or external command in my case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer as it solves my problem! lsvirtualenv does not work for me.

Answer (score 83):

If you are using `virtualenv` or Python 3's built in `venv` the above answers might not work.

If you are on Linux, just `locate` the `activate` script that is always present inside a env.

```sh
locate -b '\activate' | grep "/home"
```

This will grab all Python virtual environments present inside your home directory.

For Mac Users, `find` works pretty good too

```sh
find $HOME -name "*activate" -type f
```

[See Demo Here](https://bhupesh-v.github.io/find-all-python-virtual-environments-in-your-system/)

Comment: This should be the top answer as it works on ubuntu with both: `virtualenv` as well as `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: @PeDro Why should working on Ubuntu be the criterion for the best answer?  What about people on other Linux distros?  What about Windows users?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The answer mentions that this works for Linux. I validated it on Ubuntu and voted for it. The accepted answer  doesn't work for both: virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. This one does. Please don't get it wrong

Comment: agreed, best answer, because of flexibility and working without any setup.

Comment: This works for OS X, where the above answers did not work for me with `virtualenv`

Comment: i'm in ubuntu linux and `locate` is not installed but the `find` command did the job

Answer (score 70):

Run [workon](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#workon) with no argument to list available environments.

Comment: `workon` (without parameters) is the best way! It's a command of Virtualenvwrapper. `lsvirtualenv` is a command proper to Virtualenv.

Comment: `workon` lists all projects, but not every virtualenv will have an associated projet.

Answer (score 15):

**For conda created env use:**

```sh
conda info --envs  # or 
conda info -e      # or 
conda env list
```

**For virtualenvwrapper created env use:**

```sh
lsvirtualenv
```

Answer (score 13):

If you came here from Google, trying to find where your previously created *virtualenv* installation ended up, and why there is no command to find it, here's the low-down.

The design of `virtualenv` has a fundamental flaw of not being able to keep track of it's own created environments. Someone was not quite in their right mind when they created `virtualenv` without having a rudimentary way to keep track of already created environments, and certainly not fit for a time and age when most pip requirements require multi-giga-byte installations, which should certainly **not** go into some obscure `.virtualenvs` sub-directory of your *~/home*.

IMO, the created virtualenv *directory* should be created in `$CWD` **and** a file called `~/.virtualenv` (in *home*) should keep track of the name and path of that creation. Which is a darn good reason to use *Conda/Miniconda3* instead, which does seem to keep good track of this.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386421/1147688), the only way to keep track of this, is to install yet another package called [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). If you don't do that, you will have to search for the created directory by yourself. Clearly, if you don't remember the *name* or the *location* it was created with/at, you will most likely never find your virtual environment again...

One try to remedy the situation in windows, is by putting the following functions into your powershell profile:

```
# wrap virtualenv.exe and write last argument (presumably 
# your virtualenv name) to the file: $HOME/.virtualenv.
function ven { if( $args.count -eq 0) {Get-Content ~/.virtualenv } else {virtualenv.exe "$args"; Write-Output ("{0} `t{1}" -f $args[-1],$PWD) | Out-File -Append $HOME/.virtualenv }}

# List what's in the file or the directories under ~/.virtualenvs
function lsven { try {Get-Content ~/.virtualenv } catch {Get-ChildItem ~\.virtualenvs -Directory | Select-Object -Property Name } }
```

<sub>**WARNING:** This will write to `~\.virtualenv`...</sub>

---

If you use the **recommended** [`venvlink`](https://github.com/np-8/venvlink), then you can add the following powershell function, to list your available virtual environments.

```
# List what's in the directories of C:\venvs\
#   - installed venvlink, with venvs in C:\venvs\
#   - venvlink uses: ~/.venvlinkrc
function lsven { Get-ChildItem -Path C:\venvs\ -Name }
```

<sub>This can surely be improved to automatically detect the *venvlink* root directory.</sub>

Comment: Really appreciate the explainer on this as this was my exact situation.

Comment: There is also a nice package called [**`venvlink`**](https://github.com/np-8/venvlink) that not only keep track of where the files go, but allow you full control of putting all the different virtual environments in the same directory (even if you code is elsewhere) and either copy or link them to each other.

Answer (score 8):

To list all virtualenvs

```
conda env list
```

Output:

```
# conda environments:
#
                         D:\Programs\Anaconda3
                         D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\notebook
                         D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\snakes
                         D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes
base                  *  D:\Programs\Miniconda3
gluon                    D:\Programs\Miniconda3\envs\gluon
```

Comment: This will list only conda environments, not those generated by pip.

Answer (score 6):

If using Anaconda `conda env list`

If using Python3 `lsvirtualenv`  after you installed `pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 2):

Use below bash command to locate all virtual env in your system. You can modify the command according to your need to get in your desired format.

```
locate --regex "bin/activate"$ | sed 's/bin\/activate$//'
```

Comment: How do you know it belongs to pip? I can think of many apps having that in their paths and not even using python. But I guess this is better than nothing! Also there is already an answer using `locate` that is better because it's using the `-b` flag.

Answer (score 0):

How do I find the Django virtual environment name if I forgot?. It is very Simple, you can find from the following location, if you forgot Django Virtual Environment name on Windows 10 Operating System.

c:\Users<name>\Envs<Virtual Environments>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can find is we can check the installed python directory.

As for windows, the default directory for **virtualenv** and **pipenv** is.

```
/c/User/<username>/.virtualenv/
```

The directory(folder) inside the above directory shows all virtualenvs

Example -

```
ankit@ankit-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/study
$ ls /c/Users/ankit/.virtualenvs/
get_env_details*  postactivate*    postmkproject*     postrmvirtualenv*  predeactivate*  premkvirtualenv*  study-OwW1UW_H/
initialize*       postdeactivate*  postmkvirtualenv*  preactivate*       premkproject*   prermvirtualenv*
```

**study-OwW1UW_H/** is the only directory and virtualenv in the above example.

Answer (score -1):

This works on **Windows only**:

If you are trying to find all envs created using virtualenv
search for ***"activate_this.py"*** or ***"pip-selfcheck.json"***

Answer (score -1):

if you're working on windows and conda, typing `conda info --envs` in cmd will show all the existing virtual envirentment.

Comment: This was already mentioned.