# How to list all python virtual environments in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, debian, virtual-environment

I have more than one Python environment configured in my Debian OS. Is there a way to list all configured environments in Linux?

This is different from the possible duplicate as indicated in the comment below.  I mean virtual environments created using `virtualenv` only.

Comment: `whereis python` gives you a nice list

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this gave me all different installed versions of python, but not the virtual environments.

Comment: The command `lsvirtualenv -l` in the duplicate question you are referring to, gives me `command not found`.

Comment: Define what do you mean by "python environment". Do you mean virtual environments created using `virtualenv` only? Both these and other python installations? Different python installations (but no virtual envs)? AFAIK `virtualenv` does **not** keep track of all the envs you create and as such there's no built-in way to do what you want. The `lsvirtualenv` command is part of the [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) program which adds some functionality to virtualenv. You'll have to use `find` and look for specific files that are created by virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, I mean virtual environments created using `virtualenv` only.

Comment: This is also true for windows.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If only using the lowly `virtualenv ...{directory}` to create a virtualenv, then there is just some directory somewhere that has that specific environment in it. You can only "list" these by running `find` on your `$HOME` directory  (or any other list of directories you might have used to create virtualenvs) looking for python installations. Hopefully some convention was followed like storing them all in `~/virtualenvs`.  (See also [Where should virtualenvs be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184846/where-should-virtualenvs-be-created) )

If using `virtualenvwrapper`, then as mentioned, use the command `lsvirtualenv` to list envs that were created with `mkvirtualenv`. They are all in `~/.virtualenvs` by default.  See https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html

If using `conda`, you can list virtual envs created via `conda create --name {my_env} [...]`, using either `conda info --envs` or `conda env list`. See https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#list-all-environments

Comment: My god! Who in their right mind created `virtualenv` without having a rudimentary way to keep track of already created environments? And who in their right mind would wan't to keep all their gigabyte created pip envs in their *home* under a `.virtualenv` sub-directory? IMHO, the created virtualenv *directory* should be created in `$CWD` and a file called `~/.virtualenvs` (in *home*) should keep track of the name and path of that creation.

Comment: @not2qubit I think it is sometimes beneficial to do the opposite: put all the virtual environments to a common folder and just a link to the virtual environment in the project folder. This way, if you have automatic backups (meaning Dropbox or OneDrive on Windows, for example), the virtual environment files are not backed up unnecessarily. This way it is also possible to reuse virtual environments. I have created even a simple package to make this easier and so far have liked the arrangement.

Comment: @np8 Yes, your [venvlink](https://github.com/np-8/venvlink) look promising.