# what's command to list all the virtual environments in venv?

Tags: python-3.x

I know in conda I can use `conda env list` to get a list of all conda virtual environments, what's the corresponding command in python `venv` that can list all the virtual environments in a given `venv`? also, is there any way I can print/check the directory of current venv? somehow I have many projects that have same name `.venv` for their virtual environment and I'd like to find a way to verify which venv I'm in. Thanks

Comment: Probably this would help you  answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745143/how-to-list-all-python-virtual-environments-in-linux

Comment: @stark9190 the link answers how to list environments created by `virtualenv` (python2). But what is the command for listing environments created by `venv` (python3)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all the virtual environments created with venv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873454/how-can-i-list-all-the-virtual-environments-created-with-venv)

Answer (score 2):

Virtual environments are simple a set of files in a directory on your system. You can find them the same way you would find images or documents with a certain name. For example, if you are using Linux or macOS, you could run `find / | grep bin/activate` in terminal. Not too sure about Windows but I suspect you can search for something similar in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use lsvirtualenv in the parent directory in CMD. This will show the list of all venv. if you want to open a specific one from the listed type workon(env_name). Then hit Enter

Comment: I tried this in the parent directory of my venv environments and got `The term 'lsvirtualenv' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`