# How can I list all the virtual environments created with venv?

Tags: python, python-venv

Someone's just asked me how to list all the virtual environments created with `venv`.

I could only think of searching for [`pyvenv.cfg`](http://ttps://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) files to find them. Something like:

```
from pathlib import Path

venv_list = [str(p.parent) for p in Path.home().rglob('pyvenv.cfg')]
```

This could potentially include some false positives. Is there a better way to list all the virtual environment created with `venv`?

NB: The question is about `venv` specifically, **NOT** Anaconda, virtualenv, etc.

Comment: please try this command -> lsvirtualenv

Comment: @EddwinPaz I'm asking specifically about the `venv` module.

Comment: do a grep on the using OS I read some of the venv usage and it creates a folder. the other idea is to see all running processes further that I don't know how to possibly approach a solution. looking into it.

Comment: There are many different packages offering tool(s) for centralizing virtual environments into one folder. While they do not help you searching the current virtual envs, they offer a handy way to keep everything organized in the future.

Comment: Did you find a bulletproof way for serching/listing venvs?

Comment: @np8 Not really. My best guess is looking for pyvenv.cfg and eliminate the potential false-positive by testing functionality of each candidate, e.g. the success of activate command perhaps?

Comment: I did similar search on Windows when I had to change workplace laptop, since all venvs had to be recreated. I'm guessing I searched for a combination of `activate` script, and `python.exe`, perhaps also `site-packages`.

Comment: I finally had some time for a deep dive tor the topic (I also developed a package for venv management on Windows, and therefore had own interest), and found out the absolute minimum criterion for a folder to be a virtual environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Linux/macOS this should get most of it

`find ~ -d -name "site-packages" 2>/dev/null`

Looking for directories under your home that are named "site-packages" which is where  `venv` puts its pip-installed stuff.  the /dev/null bit cuts down on the chattiness of things you don't have permission to look into.

Or you can look at the specifics of a particular expected file.  For example, `activate` has `nondestructive` as content.  Then you need to look for a pattern than matches venv but not anaconda and the rest.

`find ~ -type f -name "activate" -exec egrep -l nondestructive /dev/null {} \; 2>/dev/null`

##### macos `mdfind`

On macos, this is is pretty fast, using `mdfind` (`locate` on Linux would probably have similar performance.

```
mdfind -name activate | egrep /bin/activate$|  xargs -o egrep -l nondestructive 2>/dev/null | xargs -L 1 dirname | xargs -L 1 dirname
```

So we :

- look for all activate files
- egrep to match only bin/activate files (`mdfind` matches on things like `.../bin/ec2-activate-license`)
- look for that `nondestructive` and print filename where there is a  match.
- the 2 `xargs -L 1 dirname` allow us to "climb up" from `/bin/activate` to the virtual env's root.

##### Helper function with `-v` flag to show details.

```
jvenvfindall(){  # search for Python virtual envs.  -v for verbose details


    unset verbose
    
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts 'v' OPTION; do
      case "$OPTION" in
    
        v)
          verbose=1
          ;;
    
        ?)
          ;;
      esac
    done
    shift "$(($OPTIND -1))"
    
    
    local bup=$PWD
    for dn in $(mdfind -name activate | egrep /bin/activate$|  xargs -o egrep -l nondestructive 2>/dev/null | xargs -L 1 dirname | xargs -L 1 dirname) 
    do

        if [[ -z "$verbose" ]]; then
            printf "$dn\n"
        else
            printf "\n\nvenv info for $dn:\n"
            cd $dn
            echo space usage, $(du -d 0 -h)
            #requires the jq and jc utilities... to extract create and modification times
            echo create, mod dttm: $(stat . | jc --stat | jq '.[]|{birth_time, change_time}')
            tree -d -L 1 lib


        fi
    done

    cd $bup
}
```

##### output:

```
...

venv info for /Users/me/kds2/issues2/067.pip-stripper/010.fixed.p1.check_venv/venvtest:
space usage, 12M .
create, mod dttm: { "birth_time": "Apr 16 13:04:43 2019", "change_time": "Sep 30 00:00:39 2019" }
lib
└── python3.6

...
```

Hmmm, disk usage is not that bad, but something similar for node_modules might save some real space.

Comment: Another option is `find ~ -type l -name python` to find all symlinks to python binary

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 that would work too.  the funny thing is that, if you copy a venv's files, says `cp -r venv1/ venv2` then `source venv2/bin/activate` points at venv1's Python.  so, it's close, but not quite as self-contained as say copying a directory with a`.git` in it. that's because the paths are hardcoded at install time.

Comment: Interesting about copying the venv folder. I can't think of anything else than looking for files. Look for `python` and you get all forms of python's interpreter, look for `pyvenv.cfg` and you get only the virtual env created with `venv`. Maybe?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin pyenv.cfg would be a good bet then.  just do it via the OS & file system, not within a Python script.  even if you needed programmatic access, you can easily subprocess `find` - I've launched simple `grep` on huge files rather than doing line by line Python for example.  not something I'd normally do but I was really trying to optimize and letting the OS and its utilities do the work ended up much faster.

Comment: @JLPeyret Agreed about using the os as long as I don't have to use `sed`.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin. Have you looked at `sd`, a rust-based sed replacement for changing files (not bash strings)?  Rough edges, but quite an improvement. https://github.com/chmln/sd

Comment: Thank you--this yielded some very interesting results and reminded me of things I'd done (installed) long ago.

Answer (score 4):

The standard library [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) does not keep track of any of the created virtual environments. Therefore, the only possibility to list all of them is to search for your hard drive for folders that meet certain criterion.

The [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) gives quite good listing about what should be included in a folder so that it is a virtual environment. Also this [blog post](https://meribold.org/python/2018/02/13/virtual-environments-9487/) explains part of the virtual environment internals quite well. The definition of a virtual environment is

> A Python virtual environment in its simplest form would consist
> of nothing more than a copy or symlink of the **Python binary**
> accompanied by a **pyvenv.cfg** file and a **site-packages** directory. (PEP 405)

In summary, you will have to search your hard drive for folders that:

#### Linux / macOS

- Has `pyvenv.cfg` with `home` key*
- Has `bin/python3` or  `bin/python`
- Has `lib/<python-version>/site-packages/`, where `<python-version>` is for example `python3.3`.
- Optional: If created with `venv`, has also `bin/activate` ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)). A folder is considered virtual environment even if this would be lacking.  ([PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/))

#### Windows

- Has `pyvenv.cfg` with `home` key*
- Has `Script/python.exe`
- Has `lib/<python-version>/site-packages/`, where `<python-version>` is for example `python3.3`.
- Optional: If created with `venv`, has also `Scripts/activate.bat` and `Scripts/Activate.ps1` ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)). A folder is considered virtual environment even if these would be lacking. ([PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/))

#### * `pyvenv.cfg`

The `pyvenv.cfg` can actually be in the same folder or one subfolder above the `python` executable. The `pyvenv.cfg` that belongs to a virtual environment must have `home = <home>` row, where `<home>` is the directory containing the Python executable used to create the virtual environment. (PEP 405).