# where is the package installed by "pip install" located?

Tags: python, pip

I installed a package by "pip inatall " and I want to find where the package is located on my disk.

I found these post: 
[List all virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212140/list-all-virtualenv) and [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory), but they didn't answer my question.

My terminal doesn't know the commands 'lsvirtualenv' or 'workon'.
The function site.getsitepackages() returned:

> ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

None of these directories included 'okcupyd'.

Comment: Have you tried looking inside your `site-packages` folder? Usually in something like `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: @mangoHero1, I use ubuntu, and I was looking for /usr/lib/python/site-packages. I didn't find such a directory.

Comment: I'll be more specific. The package I want to install is: https://github.com/IvanMalison/okcupyd

Comment: OK. I used: 
imoprt <package_name>
print <package_name>.__path__
and I got the path. It was /home/CrazySynthax/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package_name>