# How to get the list of the python virtual environments installed on a linux server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6, python-venv

I am new to linux environments. I have a linux server on which I have installed python3 in some virtual environment (but I no longer remember the name of the virtual environment). I know that if I were using anaconda on a windows computer, I would do the following to get the virtual environment names.

```
conda info --envs
```

The question is how do I get the list of all the virtual environments on my linux server and the path to those environments? In particular, I want a link to the bin folder containing my python3 so that I can activate my virtual environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212140/list-all-virtualenv) and [How to list all python environments in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745143/how-to-list-all-python-environments-in-linux)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have created the virtual environments with the python `pip install virtualenv` command, run the command

```
$locate activate
```

It will list down all the folders having 'activate' in it. Among those you can find the virtual environment folders you created. Remember, the virtual env folders are of this form `your_env_name/bin/activate` under the parent folder where it was created.

Comment: Nice, can even shorted the list to look at with: locate --regex "/bin/activate$"